# Зацикливание метода обработки коллизий

Tags: алгоритм, хеширование

При обработке коллизии для поиска свободной ячейки методом двойного хеширования цикл "зациклился". В методе написано, что такое возможно для данного метода. Преподша говорила, что надо таблицу увеличить в 1.5-2 раза и сделать все заново.

Только вот вопрос: как определить, что он зациклился? Через какое-то число итераций, отслеживать на повторяемость вычисленных адресов или еще как-то? В-общем как отследить зацикливание?

Comment: Для вычисления индекса использовать хэш, в случае коллизии взять хэш от хэша; чтобы не было зацикливания, сохранить значение хэша от хэша в другой хэш-таблице (или проверить, нет ли уже этого хэша от хэша в той хэш-таблице), для этого сначала вычислить хэш от хэша от хэша и в случае коллизии уже вычислять не просто ъэш от хэша от хэша, а хэш от хэша от хэша от хэша

Comment: Я если честно знатно поржал с последних слов. Ну да ладно... Попробую понять и применить...

Comment: А я, если честно, не понял, понял ли OP шутку :)

Answer (score 1):

При правильном алгоритме зацикливания быть не может!

Либо, перебирая элементы таблицы, начиная с вычисленного по хэшу элемента, нашли искомый ключ, либо нашли пустой элемент - значит искомого ключа в таблице нет. Максимальное число просмотров - размер таблицы. Т.е. если сделали N (размер таблицы) шагов, то таблица переполнена (выходим из функции).

Для уменьшения длин цепочек коллизий надо сделать так, чтобы размер таблицы и шаг по ней были взаимно простыми числами. Обычно делают таблицу размер которой простое число, а шаг берут как хэш от хэша.

Answer (score 1):

Цикл может зациклиться по нескольким причинам:

1) Вся таблица заполнена ключами. Она возникает при коэффициенте заполнения таблицы равному 1. Эта проблема решается, если сделать перехеширование. Для каждого ключа из таблицы применить снова хеширование и отправить его во вторую таблицу, размер которой больше. Пример кода:

```
void CHashTable::rehash() {
std::vector<string> oldTable(table.size()*2);
std::for_each(oldTable.begin(),oldTable.end(),[](string &n) { n=N; });
std::swap( table, oldTable );
keysCount = 0;
for(int i = 0; i<oldTable.size();++i){
    if(oldTable[i]!=N)          
    {
        Add(oldTable[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

2) Ошибка в хеш-функции. Дело в том, что возвращаемый параметр второй хеш-функции должен быть взаимно прост с размерами таблицы. Например, если размер таблицы - степень 2, то подойдёт любое нечётное число. А если размер таблицы простое число - то подойдёт любая хеш-функция.

3)Неверное условие в цикле. Нужно посмотреть, какие условия остановки цикла. Главное - число итераций не должно быть больше размера таблицы.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы отслеживать зацикливание, придётся городить ещё одну структуру. Идите другим путём. Есть вариант, если возможны коллизии, предусматривать хранение не отдельных занчений по хэшу, а  список значений, с совпадающим хэшем. Ну, например, можно сортированный список сделать